# Xamarin Splash screen example does not work in landscape mode on a phone. How to fix it?

Tags: android, xamarin, splash-screen

I downloaded the splash screen example from the Xamarin website:
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/creating_a_splash_screen/

I compiled it and ran it on my phone:
http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_fresh_s7390-5841.php

It was working fine when holding my phone in portrait mode (vertical). The splash screen became directly visible and after a few seconds, the view with the button became visible. When closing and restarting the application, it was still working fine.

After that, I closed it again and hold my phone in landscape (horizontal) mode. Now, I started the application again. My phone was frozen for a few seconds, the splash did not become visible. After that, I saw my view with the button.

When you try to reproduce this issue, make sure that you:

- Do not try to reproduce it on a virtual device (the behavior is different).
- Make sure that the sleep takes at least 10 seconds, then you really see what the problem is: a frozen application instead of a splash screen.
- If you do not have the Samsung Trend Lite, you try it on another small smart phone. I find it hard to imagine that this could be a "Samsung Trend Lite only" issue.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Xamarin sample](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/creating_a_splash_screen/) that you linked has big problem within it:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
public class SplashActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        Thread.Sleep(10000); // Simulate a long loading process on app startup.
        StartActivity(typeof(Activity1));
    }
}
```

The `OnCreate()` method of an `Activity` is executed on the UI thread therefore calling a `Thread.Sleep()` inside it will lock up the main thread, possibly generating an Application Not Responding (ANR) to be display to the user.

This is fault in the Xamarin docs, you **should not** run a `Thread.Sleep()` on the UI thread, especially within one of the core lifecycle callbacks for an activity.

Fix this by using a background thread to execute the sleep and then call back into the splash activity to launch the next activity:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
public class SplashActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run( () => {
            Thread.Sleep(10000); // Simulate a long loading process on app startup.
            StartActivity(typeof(Activity1));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, it should not be done on the UI thread? This also solves the problem on my device (I just discovered):             base.OnCreate(bundle);
            System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(1);
            t.Elapsed += (o, e) =>
            {
                t.Stop();
                Thread.Sleep(10000); // Simulate a long loading process on app startup.
                StartActivity(typeof(Activity1));
            };
            t.Start();

Comment: That's more or less doing the same thing as using a background thread. That's also a nice solution!

Comment: In response to putting the sleep into a background thread, try keeping it the way the Xamarin docs suggests and pressing the back button to exit the app while its starting up. Because its on the UI thread it'll lock user interaction and probably generate an ANR. Hence why you shift the delay into the background.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered another solution. It is a bit strange to use a timer but it solves the problem.

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(1);
        t.Elapsed += (o, e) =>
        {
            t.Stop();
            Thread.Sleep(10000); // Simulate a long loading process on app startup.
            StartActivity(typeof(Activity1));
        };
        t.Start();
    }
```