# Splash screen too slow in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm creating an app that shows a splash screen and then creates the main activity. I'm following this tutorial that seems pretty straight forward: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/creating_a_splash_screen/

After implementing that I can successfully see the splash but there are some times (1 out of 20) that with an S5 I see the following screen:

[image: Wrong screen]

Followed by the (right) splash (taken from the Emulator but just to make my point):

[image]

So my guess would be that sometimes Xamarin is taking to long to load the app therefore it has a delay showing the splash. Is there any way to prevent that?

**UPDATE 1**
I've followed the tutorial but I've removed the sleep for this:

```
Insights.Initialize ("<APP_KEY>", Application.Context);
StartActivity(typeof (MainActivity));
```

Comment: Did you set the correct image in the splash theme and set the theme for the activity, as in the tutorial?  It looks like your activity doesn't have a windowBackground image.  Have you checked on other versions of Android?

Comment: Yes I've set everything like the tutorial and 19 in 20 it looks good is just 1 out of 20 that shows the first screen for less than a second and then shows the second one with the right layout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin Splash screen example does not work in landscape mode on a phone. How to fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29991174/xamarin-splash-screen-example-does-not-work-in-landscape-mode-on-a-phone-how-to)

Comment: @FedericoM.Rinaldi ,i think you facing OOM IN bitmap handling.Goto Output window ,see log ,anyway samusing devices going to hell in few years ,i was face the same issue in my

Comment: @matthewrdev thanks for the reply but I'm not using the Sleep, I've updated my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example invokes the `Thread.Sleep(10000);` on the UI thread... **This will lock up the app and generate an [ANR](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html)!**

Fix it by backgrounding the sleep and then triggering the next activity:

```
namespace SplashScreen
{
    using System.Threading;

    using Android.App;
    using Android.OS;

    [Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            Task.Run (() => {
                Thread.Sleep (10000); // Simulate a long loading process on app startup.
                RunOnUiThread (() => { 
                    StartActivity (typeof(Activity1));
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I'm not using the Sleep, I've updated my question but I think you're response still applies. I will keep you posted

Answer (score 1):

Even if this post is rather old, I had a similar experience when implementing the SplashScreen and could resolve this by updating the style/theme of the SplashScreen. The screen @frederico m rinaldi sometimes sees is commonly created by using Android's default (Holo) theme.

Although you didn't supply the style applied to the SplashScreen (see `Theme = @style/Theme.Splash` of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33794545/5400351%20accepted%20answer)) , here's mine. Maybe you can check if they differ.

```
<style name="Theme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <!-- Use a fully opaque color as background. -->
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
  <!-- This removes the title bar seen within the first screen. -->
  <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <!-- Let the splash screen use the entire screen space by enabling full screen mode -->
  <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
  <!-- Hide the ActionBar (Might be already defined within the parent theme) -->
  <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

You may notice that I simply use the color black as background, because my SplashScreen uses a custom layout file instead of static image (`this.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SplashScreen);`). Also, loading the image (`drawable`) might require some time which may be the main reason you can see the default theme instead of your splash screen.
Additionally, I omitted the `android:` XML namespace for some attributes which is due to [Google's internal implementation](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/#migration-from-previous-setup%20Google's%20internal%20implementation) of the Android support library features.

Please note that in order to use the AppCompat themes, your application must include the [AppCompat support library](https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-material-design-v7-appcompat/%20AppCompat%20support%20library) and your Activity must subclass `Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatActivity`.