# Xamarin Android splash taking too much of time

Tags: xamarin.forms, splash-screen

In my xamarin forms project, my android splash screen taking too much time when opening the project.
Here is the code of splashscreen:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;

namespace Myproject.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "smartWCM", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    public class SplashActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); //Let's wait a while...
            this.StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
        }
    }
}
```

I try to comment the splash time but taking 15 seconds to show the login page. I need to show the login page within 5seconds.

Any solutions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splash screen too slow in Xamarin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33789862/splash-screen-too-slow-in-xamarin-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a better way to implement a splash screen on Android see the "Better approach" section of https://xamarinhelp.com/creating-splash-screen-xamarin-forms/